# OLE DB Destination Task adds values at the end of values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

A simple data flow causes a lot of trouble when i try to

1. read data from one column (**oracle 9.2.0.8**) and
2. directly write it to an oracle destination table (same database)

The column(**varchar2 25byte**) i **import** looks like this:

```
241200001
151200001
211200001
161200001
1231704383
```

When i select the column(**char 10byte**) of the **destination** table, it looks like this:

```
241200001
151200001 3
211200001 3
161200001 3
1231704383
```

---

The following screenshot shows the data grid between source and destinatin.Here, everything seems to be fine.

[image]

The next screenshot show, that there are zeros added and the end, but not everywhere. (This is the preview window of the destination task, but it looks the same in TOAD)

[image]

---

Inspecting the length of the values gives the following result, which seems pretty ok:

```
Select
id,
length(id) as length
from test_view


ID                           LENGTH
------------------------- ----------
42120001                           8
23120001                           8
22120001                           8
26120001                           8
25120001                           8
22120001                           8
22120001                           8
23120001                           8
18120001                           8
18120001                           8
1235800020                        10
58120001                           8
52120001                           8
52120001                           8
57120001                           8
52120001                           8
52120001                           8
```

---

For some reason, there is a value added at the end with a space. I've seen values being added between `1-3`, i really wonder where this comes from. There is no truncation occurring if you are worried about the shorter destination. When i set the destination column to `varchar2` it works, but we need to leave it as it is.

Inside the data flow, the data is a `string(25)`. So why should there be a problem with this destination?

**UPDATE:**

This is weird. I don't think the codepage warning is causing this error. The input data looks good, and the package is pretty standard. Could this really be a driver issue, or a problem/bug of the destination task?

Comment: Maybe take one of those problematic rows and paste it into a text editor like UltraEdit and see if there are any hidden characters in the field that are getting translated as values somehow?

Comment: Thanks, i tried that and it looks normal

Comment: If you run the query in TOAD or whatever oracle query tool you have, and add a LEN(mycolumn) AS column_length what do you see for these things? There's nothing in SSIS that should randomly append data to columns unless you've asked it to. My assumption is then either these values exist in your source data or you are requesting these values get modified within SSIS. Could you post a screenshot of your data flow?

Comment: Thanks @billinkc, please see my update. The length looks pretty good and i agree with you: The data shouldnt get modified within SSIS. I although get a warning "cannot recieve code page". I set AlwaysUseDefaultpage to true but that didnt work.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but which Oracle driver are you using for you SSIS connections?

Comment: @EdHarper I am using Native OLE DB driver for oracle with OraOLEDB10.dll version 10.2.0.5.00 (i hope this is the one it is using)

Comment: The error may come from an implicit conversion not working as expected. Have you tried using a `derived column` transformation in the data flow to explicitly convert `varchar(25)` to `char(10)`?

Comment: Is it possible to convert to a `char(10)`? I just wanted to try that , but i can't find a suitable function for it this list. http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms141704.aspx

Comment: @EdHarper I tried using a derived column with the expression `(DT_WSTR,10)ID`, set `ValidateExternalMedata` to false in the destination and changed `External Column ID` to `DT_WSTR`. This worked in an isolated package. Looks like this is the answer! I'll integrate it now in my main package and see the result

Comment: @stb -you should perhaps use `DT_STR` - `DT_WSTR` is equivalent to `NCHAR` (the `W` standing for "wide")

Comment: This worked, i think we got it! So external column of the destination is detected as `varchar(10)` by the package, but it is a `char(10)`. When changing it to `DT_WSTR(10)` and casting it using a derived column, it works without problems. (i tried with `DT_STR`, this didn't help. If you post an answer to this, I'll accept it. Thanks alot @EdHarper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a derived column transformation in the data flow to explicitly convert varchar(25) to char(10) - the error may come from an implicit conversion not working as expected.

Comment: I really wonder, why this is only working when i convert it to a unicode string format. The destination is definitly a char(10), so it's not unicode. Don't get that clear, does someone have a suggestion?